# Price on Application in commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

Is it possible to set a product to have as price "price on application"?
Also the Add to cart link should be changed to contact us or something like that.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more what are you tring to achieve ? What's really the "price on application" ?

Comment: for some products the customer should contact us to get the price, other products can ordered directly over the webshop. i looked "price on application" up in a dictionary and that is what i got...